# App crash when use signInWithEmailAndPassword (Firebase authentication)

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

Recently I've been forced to reset the android device I've been working with and since then my app crashes each time I try to sign-up or log-in.

**In other devices or in the emulator everything work as s it should so the problem isn't in the code (but if it's necessary I'll add it).
The Android device is: Lenovo S90-u.**

The error:

```
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdtp.zzb(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdtw.zzb(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(Unknown Source)
    at easytobook.com.easytobook.Account.LoginFragment$2.onClick(LoginFragment.java:90)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4460)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18649)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5345)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:855)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:671)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: easytobook.com.easytobook, PID: 7734
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdtp.zzb(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdtw.zzb(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(Unknown Source)
    at easytobook.com.easytobook.Account.LoginFragment$2.onClick(LoginFragment.java:90)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4460)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18649)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5345)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:855)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:671)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)


the code:

public class LoginFragment extends Fragment{
private EditText inputEmail, inputPassword;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private Button btnLogin, btnReset;

private FirebaseAuth auth;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_login, container, false );

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(); //Get Firebase auth instance

    if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class));
        getActivity().finish();
    }

    //setContentView(R.layout.fragment_login);
    inputEmail = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.email);
    inputPassword = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.password);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    btnLogin = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    btnReset = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_reset_password);

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(); //Get Firebase auth instance


    btnReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), ResetPasswordActivity.class));
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    });

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            final String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email))  //email check
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "enter mail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password))  //password check
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "enter password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            //authenticate user
            auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
                        {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                            // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                            // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            try
                            {
                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) // there was an error
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.auth_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                                else {
                                    //move to the next screen
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ProfileActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    getActivity().finish();
                                }
                            }
                            catch(Exception e)
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }

                        }
                    });
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please post your LoginFragment.java code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I edit my answer and added the code. Like I said, I dont think the problem is in the code, since in other devices it work just fine. tnx for your help

Comment: please post your correct error log...this log is not showing correct error.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @BobSnyder (found his answer to my problem in another question).
the problem was on the api. You have to install API with (Google APIs) add on. The google service on my device was out of date.